# Dialog IBM - Curl - PHP Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl, dialog

Watson has the next code:

```
 curl -u "{username}":"{password}" 
  -X POST
  --form file=@template.xml
  --form name=templateName
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/dialog/api/v1/dialogs"
```

And I have:

```
$ch = curl_init();
    $data['name'] = $this->post['name'].";type:form";
    $data['file'] = $this->getCurlValue($this->post['file'], $this->post['nombre']);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.$this->metodo);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$this->user}:{$this->pass}");

    if(count($this->post) > 0){
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    }
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    json_decode($output);
```

$this->post has...

```
$data = Request::only('name', 'file');
```

And I only get as answer: {}

What I'm missing?

Thanks everyone!... First time try to send a uploading file with curl :c

Comment: I try it with PHP and I can`t get work. Making Curl in terminal is so easy. Also, I try with "@", buuut, Curl File with "@" deprecated...

Answer (score 0):

It was simpler than I imagined.

Store:

```
$data = Request::only('name', 'file');

$nombre = time().".".Request::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
Request::file('file')->move(base_path() . '/public/dialogos/', $nombre);

$data['path'] = base_path() . '/public/dialogos/'.$nombre;
$data['file'] = $_FILES['file'];
```

Curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->url.$this->metodo);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$this->user}:{$this->pass}");

if(count($this->post) > 0){
    $datos['name'] = $this->post['name'];
    $datos['file'] = $this->getCurlValue($this->post['file'], $this->post['path']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datos);
}
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return json_decode($output);
```

getCurlValue($file, $path);

```
if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
    return curl_file_create($path, $file['type'], $file['name']);
}
$value = "@{$path};filename=" . $file['name'];
$value .= ';type=' . $file['type'];

return $value;
```

Stupid msg that said I need PUT or DELETE methods... haha